# How to achive Autocomplete using solr for nested index?

Tags: solr, autocomplete

As above is my index structure: I want to fetch manufacturer corresponding models using solr auto complete. Suppose I passed applianceCatagory=Boilers, manufacture=ariston and query string as "cla" then all models corresponding to ariston manufacture should get display.. I done some java coding to fetch the values as given below: but i am able to fetch only the models which starting with lower case character if i am passing lower case query string and same for upper case too : please help!! thanks a tone.

```
 <i>{
        "manuals": [
            {
                "applianceCategory": "Boilers",
                {
                        "manufacturer": "Ariston",
                        {
                            "models": [
                                        "CLAS HE 24 evo",
                                        "CLAS HE 30 evo",
                                        "LAP HE System 24 evo",
                                        "LAST HE System 30 evo"
                                        "clas HE",
                                        "cLAS ba",
                                        ],
                        }
                        "manufacturer": "Baxi",
                        {
                            "models": [
                                        "Baxi 1",
                                        "Baxi 2",
                                        "CLAS 3"
                                        ],
                        }

               },
            }
            {
                "applianceCategory": "Electrics",
                {
                        "manufacturer": "Lipton",
                        {
                            "models": [
                                        "PLAS HE",
                                        "PLAS HE 30",
                                        "PLAS HE 38 evo",
                                        "PLAS HE Sm 18 evo",
                                        "PLAS HEm 24 evo",
                                        "PLAS HE Syst"
                                        ],
                        }

               },
            }
        ]
    }

    Java Code:
    private static void getModelValues(SolrServer server,String queryString) throws SolrServerException{
            SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

            query.setParam("wt", "json");
            query.setQuery("Boilers").setQuery("Ariston");
            query.setFacet(true);
            query.addFacetField("models");
            query.setFacetMinCount(1);
            query.setFacetPrefix(queryString);

            QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
            List<FacetField> facetField = response.getFacetFields();
            List<String> listofModel=null;
                 for (int j = 0; j < facetField.size(); j++) {
                      listofModel = new ArrayList<String>();
                     for(Count count: facetField.get(j).getValues()){
                         listofModel.add(count.getName());
                     }
                     System.out.println("This is the model list---->"+listofModel);
                    Gson gson1 = new Gson();
                    System.out.println("Models:"+gson1.toJson(listofModel));
                 }  


        }

 <field name="manufacturer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" /> 
     <field name="models" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" required="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" /> 
     <field name="applianceCategory" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" /> 
     <field name="manual" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true" /> 
     <field name="models_autocomplete" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<!--Copy field -->   
     <copyField source="manufacturer" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="models" dest="models_autocomplete"/>
<copyField source="applianceCategory" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="manual" dest="text" /> 
    </i>
```

Comment: show us your solr schema please

Comment: Hi @omu_negru i have placed my schema code at the end of the code.. please have a look..thank in advance

Comment: [link for schema](https://github.com/11289/My-code/blob/master/schema.xml)

Comment: The schema definitions look ok. Please link the config file too. I need to look at the default query fields and the type of query parser

Comment: [link for config xml](https://github.com/11289/My-code/blob/master/solrconfig.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Your  `/sugest` `SearchHandler` defines `"spellcheck.dictionary"` twice : once for the `title_autocomplete` field and once for the `models` field. Aside from the fact that i don't know how solr behaves when having the same key specified twice, I don't see the `models_autocomplete` field specified anywhere in the config, so neither your default searches  or your sugest components use it's dictionary to query it.

EDIT :

switch `model` to `models_autocomplete` and see if that works . Also consider switching the default qParser to `edismax` and specifying multiple search fields. That is of course assuming your autosugest requests use the `/sugest` url

Comment: Can you suggest me some solution related to solrConfig ? I removed that extra "title_autocomplete". But things looking same :(
Do I need to change java code ?

Comment: Thanks for the response @omu_negru.. but still trying the same